# What are the effects of a custom kernel?

Tags: system-installation, system, kernel

I have purchased an Asus Zenbook UX305CA with an Elan 1000 trackpad using the I2C bus. Due to a timing error, the trackpad is nonfunctional in most kernels. If I compile a modified 4.5 kernel to resolve the problem, how will that change my elementary OS experience? Will I have trouble with updating packages or the operating system itself? Will a kernel modification fundamentally change the way elementary OS works?

Comment: It will break kernel updates if you compile it yourself.Shouldn't break elementary and if it does you can boot an older kernel

Comment: It might crash more often

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue, with a different Asus model, fixed by adding `i8042.nomux i8042.reset` to the kernel boot options in `/etc/grub/default`